# not replacing the img src attribute using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

i am replacing the img src attribute using javascript

my code is

```
<div class="reader" id="reader1"></div>    

    <img src="images/img_001.jpg" alt="image" id="image1"/>

</div>
```

and javascript code

```
$("#image1").attr("src").replace("images/img_001.jpg", "images/img_002.jpg");
```

the src attribute is not replacing

Comment: jQuery("#image1").attr("src", "/assets/arrow_small_left.png")

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to call `replace()`, just set the new src:

```
$("#image1").attr("src", "images/img_002.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

See http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2 :

```
$("#image1").attr("src", "images/img_002.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change a value using

```
$('#image1').attr('src', 'images/img_002.jpg');
```

If you are using:

```
$('#image1').attr('src');
```

The function will return a string. String do NOT get passed by reference, but get copied instead. So modifying it doesn't actually change it.

Comment: "jQuery doesn't has a replace() method" - no but javascript does!!

Comment: @Jamiec ah yes I didn't think of that at all! Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly set the value of `src` with:

```
$("#image1").attr("src", "images/img_002.jpg");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VFgn8/

Have a look at [jQuery doc for `attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) .

Answer (score 0):

or you can use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("#image1").prop("src", "images/img_002.jpg");
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PCCQm/)

Comment: Why? `src` is an attribute.

Comment: @David :) un believeable, you can use prop() to set the src... just see the working demo, and should cancel your down vote

Comment: yes, you *can*. But my question is why? Using `prop` doesn’t solve the problem, because the problem is a syntax error. `attr()` is perfectly correct to use since `src` is an attribute, just as the OP posted.

Comment: @David your question was, Why? src is an attribute.   src is an attribute and you can set the attribute value with prop() also

Comment: I know you *can*, but it’s not entirely correct use of `prop`. Also, it is irrelevant for this question, so I don’t think it is of any value for the poster.

Comment: @David I don’t think it is of any value for the poster. how you can say?

Comment: What is the value of bringing in an alternative syntax, that is also less correct that the one the poster already used? I mean, there are tons of other syntaxes you can use as well, but the question was not "what different syntaxes can I use to set attributes?". I downvoted because I don’t think this is a good answer, and I think I have the right arguments to prove it. So there you go.

Comment: @David its your opinion, give me the tons of syntax to use..! anyway i dnt care and dnt want to chat with u more

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the `replace` method actually returns the new string - not edits it in place.

You can achieve what you want like this:

```
$("#image1").attr("src", function(){
    return $(this).attr('src').replace("images/img_001.jpg", "images/img_002.jpg");
});
```

This sets a new value to the `src` attribute by calling the function (second parameter). This function actiually `returns` the replaced value.

Live example (check the src with developer tools): http://jsfiddle.net/4K3Dy/

Comment: not necessarily, Id still rather use the jQuery syntax for reading the `src` attribute inside the function. But I agree your way would work too!

Comment: I believe you can do `function(i, src) { return src.replace(...` too.

Comment: @david - course it will work - check the src in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4K3Dy/ - `attr('src')` just returns a string, and that string has a `replace` method!